# Change elements data by method dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

Below object appends `div` element to the `body` whenever `obj.appendDiv()` method is called.

```
var obj = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    background: "black",
    appendDiv: function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = this.width;
        div.style.height = this.height;
        div.style.background = this.background;
        document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
}
```

How to change all derived data in all appended `div`s whenever any parameters of `obj` are changed like typing `obj.width = "500px"` in console, changes all appended `div`s width.

Comment: Ehhh did you try anything?

Comment: I mean did you try to solve this somehow or do you rather not trying yourself?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea how this would be solved

Comment: And actually, I will use that way to rather larger project if I can find a solution. The code above is just a small example

Comment: If JQuery is allowed, you could use something like `$("div").css("width", "500px");`

Comment: Respectfully, if you "*have no idea*" how to approach this, don't try to develop a big project. That would be like trying to build a spaceship before you've learned to walk. You need to learn basic programming first.

Comment: JQuery is not allowed unfortunately.

Comment: By the way why `$("div").css("width", "500px");` needed here? Did you understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an array `div` elements created by `appendDiv`, a method to change `div` elements created by `appendDiv`

```js
var obj = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    background: "black",
    divs: [],
    changeDivs: function(prop, val) {
      this.divs.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style[prop] = val
      })
    },
    appendDiv: function (text) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = this.width;
        div.style.height = this.height;
        div.style.background = this.background;
        div.textContent = text || "";
        this.divs.push(div);
        document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
}

obj.appendDiv("abc");
obj.appendDiv(123);
obj.changeDivs("color", "blue")
```

Comment: After change, new divs are not retrieving changed parameters. But thank you anyway, I will do the rest.

Comment: @developer Try adding properties to `obj` which are set if `changeDivs` is called, use `if` condition within `appendDiv` to check of properties of `obj` referencing changes are defined, if `true` , apply properties, values to created `div` within `appendDiv`